# inline var in Anonymous Thread cause memory leak

Tags: multithreading, delphi, memory, firemonkey

Delphi 10.4.1 running Firemonkey, Windows 64.

Why does declaring an inline var and using it in .Synchronize cause a Memory Leak?

Is this a bug or inline variables are not supposed to use in synchronize()? (in that case, inline shouldn't this inline variable not be recognised by compiler inside synchronize()?

I can use other workarounds, but I'd like to understand this issue.

Attached is code that will demonstrate the memory leak.

```
procedure THeaderFooterForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    var
      z, y : string;
      //x : string; // this has no memory leak
    begin
      y := '12';
      var x: string := 'test';

      TThread.Synchronize(TThread.CurrentThread,
      procedure ()
      begin
        z := x+y;
      end);

    end).Start;
end;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Synchronize()` itself. The problem is related to inline variables being captured incorrectly by anonymous procedures.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the reply. my apologies that I missed out on the other thread.